# Isolating the Photo (face) on a Photo ID

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to be able to isolate and extract (and save) the photo portion of a Photo ID document, i.e. just the face -- no identifying numbers or other personal info. The document has already been uploaded onto my server. Does anyone know of a package, repo, or algorithm that might do this? Efficiency is fine, but not a strict requirement.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) is popular for this sort of thing.